# Ejecutar PHP en Firebase Host

Tags: php, html5, firebase, web

Tengo una aplicación web que quiero subir al host de Firebase, sin embargo al poner en la configuración:`{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.php"
      }
    ]
  }
}`

A la hora de ejecutar el servidor me descarga el archivo index.php, en vez de ejecutarlo, igual que cuando ejecutamos sin ningún servidor.
Mi duda es: ¿No se puede ejecutar php en el Firebase Hosting?

Comment: Puedes encontrar la respuesta en el siguiente enlace por composer: Firebase and PHP https://youtu.be/3ACxp56r7ag

Answer (score 0):

Parece que firebase no acepta archivos php.
Info: [Hosting Firebase ejecuta archivos php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/454720/hosting-firebase-ejecuta-archivos-php)

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/372629)