# Hosting Firebase ejecuta archivos php

Tags: php, firebase

Buen dia, tengo un proyecto simple donde use php, y firebase. Cuando configuré el hosting de firebase e inicié el ***firebase deploy***, accedí al link de la página pero no cargó nada, mas bien se decargó mi index.php.
Me podrian explicar si firebase acepta un index.php , y donde debo configurarlo?

Comment: No uses php, el hosting de firebase no soporta ningún lenguaje de backend porque está diseñado para almacenar archivos estáticos. Si quieres hacer server-side rendering, debes usar cloud functions o algún entorno de desarrollo para servidores. Pero ten en cuenta que para eso necesitarás entrar al plan de pago.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase ofrece servicios que facilitan la implementación de la lógica o diversos recursos de backend a tus aplicaciones.

Entendido esto, el uso que le puedes dar al servicio de hosting de Firebase es alojar tu código de frontend y que este haga uso de servicios de backend externos a firebase (en caso de que quieras utilizar lenguajes de backend diferentes a node, como php), también puedes integrar este mismo código de frontend con los distintos servicios de backend que proporciona Firebase.

Por otro lado, si requieres desarrollar la lógica de backend en php, por ejemplo, y además hacer uso de alguno de los servicios que proporciona Firebase, siempre puedes ubicar tu código de backend en otro servidor/servicio de alojamiento que soporte php e integrarle a tu código php alguna de las librerías que te permiten consumir los servicios de Firebase.

Te dejo un link hacia la documentación de Firebase en donde te detallan como realizar esto:

Para utilizar el SDK de Firebase en tu backend, consulta estos enlaces:

PHP: [ejemplo de integración con el servicio de Firebase - FireStore](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-firestore/v1.20.2/firestore/readme)

Otros lenguajes: [Integración del SDK de Firebase Admin a tu servidor](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#node.js)